# Is the Fatima prophecy still relevant in the 21st century?

Tags: catholicism, virgin-mary, prophecy, apparitions, fatima

At Fatima, in a vision, Our Lady told Lucia Dos Santos that "Russia will spread its errors throughout the world, raising up wars and persecutions against the Church. The good will be martyred, the Holy Father will have much to suffer, and various nations will be annihilated". After the assimilation of several countries into the USSR, the atheism inherent in Marixist Communism, the attempted assassination of Pope John Paul II.  I'd imagine most people thought this was "all she wrote" as my grandpa would say.

But if you read the news today, you might think we're just getting started.  It starts with spreading lies, turn to wars, wars to persecutions, persecutions will result in martyrdom, etc... Are there any reasons to believe that the visions definitively were for the 20th century and not perpetually until Russia is actually consecrated?

What do the modern mystagogues and interpreters of visions say about the vision's relevance in the 21st century? What notions do they have about how we actually get to the end of this?

Comment: Regarding notions about getting to the end of this ... pray the Rosary!

Answer (score 2):

**Is the Fatima prophecy still relevant in the 21st century?**

**Absolutely**

At least according to Pope Benedict XVI, who thinks it is not only still relevant, but not yet complete.

> At Mass this morning in the Fatima shrine's square, Pope Benedict said that it would be "mistaken" to consider the prophetic mission of the apparitions at Fatima complete. It continues to be relevant in that it continually invites men and women of good faith “to save the city of man,” he told the 500,000 people gathered for the feast of Our Lady of Fatima.
>
> The Holy Father presided over Mass from the steps of the Church of the Most Holy Trinity in Fatima this morning. May 13, the Solemnity of Blessed Mary Virgin of Fatima and that of the Ascension, marks the 10th anniversary of the beatification of the shepherd-children Jacinta and Francisco.
>
> The faithful can also draw inspiration from the way Jacinta, Francisco and Sister Lucia gave their entire lives to God, he said. “Blessed Jacinta, in particular, proved tireless in sharing with the needy and in making sacrifices for the conversion of sinners. Only with this fraternal and generous love will we succeed in building the civilization of love and peace.”
>
> **Turning to the message delivered by Our Lady of Fatima, the Holy Father said, “we would be mistaken to think that the prophetic mission of Fatima is complete.”** - [Fatima's prophetic mission not complete, Pope declares on Solemnity](https://www.catholicnewsagency.com/news/19653/fatimas-prophetic-mission-not-complete-pope-declares-on-solemnity)

Answer (score -1):

Pope Benedict, in 2010, concluded his message about the Fatima message with the prayer:

> “May the seven years which separate us from the centenary of the
> apparitions hasten the fulfillment of the prophecy of the triumph of
> the Immaculate Heart of Mary, to the glory of the Most Holy Trinity.”

Now that we are nearly five years on from that centenary, the question of whether the "Fatima prophecy" is still relevant in this 21st century is worth asking. ***If it gave prophecies that harmonized perfectly with all the Bible's prophecies about the build-up to Christ's sudden return, then it could be seen as confirming the prophecies God had already caused to be written down*** (the last ones being around 95 A.D.) That would be significant.

So, has a comparison been done by Catholic authorities, to enable that question to be answered? Can they point to book, chapter and verse in the Bible with specific end-time prophecies, and line up any of the Fatima statements with them?

I would suggest that that would give the answer.  And the most important claim to square with Bible prophecy would be regarding what Pope Benedict said, about the "prophecy of the triumph of the Immaculate Heart of Mary". It would first need to be shown that the Bible prophesied a "triumph of the Immaculate Heart of Mary". I'm going to make a flat statement, that the Bible makes no such mention of any such thing, either in a prophecy or in any other of its statements.

But if anyone can show me to be wrong, please hasten to quote from the Bible where it says that. I will promptly retract my flat statement. But if Catholic views about that are wrong (i.e. unbiblical) then why should anyone consider anything else those Fatima prophecies claim?

Further, t**he idea proposed, that Russia will yet be consecrated, contradicts the end-time prophecies in the Bible book of Revelation,** where all the nations are invisibly led by demonic powers to line up against God - when they will be wiped out in judgment, not consecrated. Have a read of Revelation chapter 14, verses 12 to 20.